# Understanding repartition in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My question is a bit conceptual and related to how things work under the hood. I have written below code related to repartiton.

```
df_cube = spark.createDataFrame([ ("Sachin" , "M"), ("Dipti", "F") , ("Roshani", "F"), ("Tushar", "M"), ("Satyendra", "M") ], ["Name" , "Gender"] )
data = df_cube.union(df_cube).repartition("Gender")
data.show()
```

The above code gives me below output.

```
+---------+------+
|     Name|Gender|
+---------+------+
|    Dipti|     F|
|   Sachin|     M|
|  Roshani|     F|
|   Tushar|     M|
|Satyendra|     M|
|    Dipti|     F|
|   Sachin|     M|
|  Roshani|     F|
|   Tushar|     M|
|Satyendra|     M|
+---------+------+
```

After that I repartition by Name and Gender both and I get below output.

```
df_name = data.repartition(7, "Name", "Gender")
df_name.show()
```

```
+---------+------+
|     Name|Gender|
+---------+------+
|   Tushar|     M|
|   Tushar|     M|
|Satyendra|     M|
|Satyendra|     M|
|   Sachin|     M|
|    Dipti|     F|
|   Sachin|     M|
|    Dipti|     F|
|  Roshani|     F|
|  Roshani|     F|
+---------+------+
```

My main question is that how can I figure out the ordering of the rows when I call out repartition on one column and two columns as depicted above . How does Spark rearrange the rows . On my local machine it shows two partitions by default , is there a way to view what rows goes into which partition and after repartitioning , how to view which partition have which rows. Please help me answer these both queries , if possible, in a verbose manner

Comment: Spark creates for each Transformation and action its own Dataframe. You can check how the job is done with ``df.toDebugString()``.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I figure out the ordering of the rows when I call out repartition

No you can't and in fact it should be irrelevant. Ordering is for when you query the data back  ie. `select from where order by`, you can event make it a "view" for users. In short, ordering cannot be guaranteed because Spark distribute and parallelize data.

> is there a way to view what rows goes into which partition and after repartitioning

Yes, you can experiment with the following snippet which will show what is inside each partition.

```py
for i, part in enumerate(df.rdd.glom().collect()):
    print({i: part})
```